# Awarding bounty rep after expiration

Tags: support, bounty

I recently started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303118/chrome-status-cancelled-on-network-dev-tools-when-playing-html5-video) and waited for an answer. Finally I figured it was a bug out of my control and posted that as an answer just 1 hour before the bounty expired. That was the only answer that was posted and it did not get any votes. Now it is in grace period where the bounty will be auto awarded.

Now my intention is NOT to try to get my bounty refunded or anything like that. I paid the bounty to gain attention to my question and maybe I got that attention. I was just curious as to what happens now.

Comment: Since there wasn't an answer that was not posted by you with at least two upvotes, and there's not an answer that you can manually award the bounty to, the bounty just disappears. It's essentially just paying for advertisement if it doesn't get awarded. But +1 for not assuming that you should get refunded.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are no qualifying answers, and your bounty will just expire without being auto-awarded.

To auto-award, one of the the following two conditions must be met:

- You accepted an answer (not your own) that was posted after the bounty started, or
- An answer (not your own) was posted after the bounty was started that has a score of 2 or higher.

It is technically possible for someone to post an answer during the grace period that would still qualify before the bounty is auto-awarded.

Once the grace period has passed, the bounty will be gone, having been paid for the advertising period. Nothing else will happen.

Comment: "if you don't have an answer, or only a self-answer, the grace period is still in effect for 24 hours. Answers posted during this time period **may be awarded** the bounty" ([FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/165773)). Per my reading, this is for both manual and automatic award. Grace period seems to only drop the question from the featured list

Comment: @gnat: ah, I misremembered then.

Comment: People do abuse the bounty system by posting an answer with a sockpuppet account and awarding the bounty to it.